# Meteor: How to show route data on the same url?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

There is a collection of Posts.
Creating a `Link` of each post on the home page. 
Need to show post specific data when a link is clicked. 
It works fine and show data on new url but don't do anything if Url is given as root `/`.

**HomePage.html**

```
<template name="homePage">
    <h2>Welcome to home page!</h2>
    {{#each posts}}
        <a href="{{pathFor 'postPage'}}">Link</a>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

**Router.js**

```
this.route('postPage', {
    path: '/posts/:_id',
    data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id)}
});
```

**Post.html**

```
<template name="postPage">
    <div class="container">
        <span>{{note}}</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

Issue is that post specific data goes to a new url and user has to click back to click on other links.
It didn't work when I tried to change router path to `path:/`

> Want to show post specific data on home page itself with all the links on top of it.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems that it's the expected behavior, right? Can you explain a little bit more what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Perhaps [`Router.go()`](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#using-routes) is what you wanted to use?